# PHP Page Not Found error even though page exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

When I invoke http://localhost/myapp, this is displaying the login screen (index.php) and after accepting and validating the credentials, throws a 404 Page Not found error.  When I debugged, it goes into the "if" statement but fails to load the page.  `dashboard.php` is available under views folder.

**index.php**

```
    //validation section

    if($usr2)
    {
            header('location: http://localhost/myapp/application/views/dashboard');
            //redirect("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/myapp/application/views/dashboard");
    }
```

**.htaccess (in the htdocs folder)**

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /myapp/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - 
    #RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php) 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
    # browser requests PHP
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: htacess file must be in root directory. where your `index.php`,

Comment: I have placed .htaccess in the root directory (and restarted Apache) but still getting the same error

Comment: After user logins in you site. you redirecting to `dashboard.php` but server can not found page? am i correct ?

Comment: @ttrasn: you are right but the php page exists.  Server responds that the page is not found.

Comment: what is your framework ? I thin its about your framework handler

Comment: If I use http://localhost/myapp/application/views/dashboard.php in the browser, then I get <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function base_url() in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\application\views\dashboard.php:12

Comment: Do you using codeigniter framework ?

Comment: yes, I am using codeigniter framework.

Comment: Ok. to use `base_url` function. you must load the url helper. add this `$this->load->helper('url');` on your controller

Comment: class Admin extends CI_Controller
    {
 public $zone_name = CUSTOM_ZONE_NAME;
 
 // construct call
 public function __construct()
 {
 parent::__construct();
 $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
 $this->load->helper('date');
 $this->load->helper('file');
 $this->load->library('form_validation');
 $this->load->model('Model_admin','home');
 $this->load->database();
 $this->load->library('session');
 $this->load->library('image_lib');
 $this->load->helper('cookie');
 $this->load->helper('url');
 $this->load->library('email');
 session_start();
 }

Comment: Sorry I didnt know about this framework. maybe some one else can help you

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to answer, but capitalize "Location" and add the extension to your path:

`header('Location: http://localhost/myapp/application/views/dashboard.php');`

Comment: `HTTP` headers are case-insenstive. `Start-Case` is only for pretty-print, easy on eyes.